# Signed release apk not generating react native using android studio

Tags: react-native, android-studio, expo

when i am trying to generate a Signed APK using android studio i am getting this error.

Failed to connect to the packager server. If you did not start this build by running 'react-native run-android', you can start the packager manually by running 'react-native start' in the project directory. (Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8081)

Answer (score 1):

You can try below command it will create signed APK for you.

```sh
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle && cd ./android && ./gradlew app:assembleRelease
```

Make sure you have below information in gradle.properties.

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=your.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=XXXXXXX
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=XXXXXXX
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=XXXXXXX
```

Also, add below code in build.Gradle(App) file

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
```

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
i am getting this error


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s